# please explain below command

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, variable

```
getDateFormat() {
  year=`echo $1 | awk -F"-" '{print $2}'`
  mm=`echo $1 | awk -F"-" '{print $3}'`
  i=1
  for x in January February march april may july jun august September October November December
  do
    if [ $mm -eq $ii ]; then
      month="$x"
      break
    fi
    ii=`expr $ii + 1`
  done
  mday=`echo $1 | awk -F"_" '{print $1}' | awk -F"-" '{print $4}'`
  tmp_date="${mday}_${month}_$year
}
```

I would like to know What does the above function do?

```
$ awk '$2 == "1" { print $0 }' cols.txt
```

Where the match occurs, print the entire line. But what this command returns

```
echo $1 | awk -F"-" '{print $2}'
```

`$ii` - What is this?

```
i=1;
echo $ii
```

It didn't print anything.

Comment: One cannot explain this abomination of code. From uninitialized variables (`$ii` used in a test) to inconsistent spelling and capitalization of the months, to an undocumented and clearly uncommon input requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is the first *positional parameter*, i.e. argument to the function. `awk -F-` sets `awk`s field separator to a dash, and `print $2` prints the second field. So from `aa-bb-cc`, you'd get `bb`.

Presumably the function expects to be called as `getDateFormat something-2017-06` which looks odd, but the year is picked from the second dash-separated field.

`$ii` would refer to a variable, but it's not set before the test `if [ $mm -eq $ii ];` so the test sees `[ 123 -eq ]` (with `123` probably some number picked from `$1`). That causes an error since the operator `-eq` is missing the other operand.

Comment: `ii` is undefined on the first iteration, but that's semantically zero; on subsequent iterations, it gets incremented. I don't think the logic is entirely correct, but with a few fixes, the loop would convert -- horribly clumsily -- from a month name to a month number. (Notice also how the month names use erratic capitalization and abbreviation conventions, and how July is incorrectly listed before June.)

Comment: I guess with `ii=1` instead of `i=1` it would superficially work for many month names.

Comment: `mm` *is* set before the loop, apparently to the month name.

Comment: @tripleee, without changing from `i=1` to `ii=1`, I get an error in bash on the first loop, so I think it needs to be set prior to the first loop iteration as you subsequently noted.

Comment: @tripleee, sorry, my bad on the `mm`. But since `$ii` is unquoted, it resolves to nothing, so that still doesn't work... And even when quoted, I think the empty string would give an error from `-eq`.

Comment: I wondered if by `$ii` the intention _may_ have been `echo ${i}i` which would have output `1i`.

Comment: Thanks all for your response. So the error is $ii. Tis command is not a parameter or positional parameters. Also  $ii would refer to a variable, but it's not set. So this is buggy. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Also please help me on Would you rewrite this function and explain why?